# How to remove duplicates from Object List based on Condition

Tags: c#, linq

```js
var incidents = new List<SMIncident>();
while (reader.Read())
 {
  SMIncident smIncident = new SMIncident();
  smIncident.GCSSReferenceNo = reader.GetString(0);
  smIncident.assignmentGroup = reader.GetString(1); 
  incidents.Add(smIncident);
 }
```

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sTmB.jpg)

I need to remove duplicates from List based on certain condition. 
E.g.,

```html
 xxxx    t1
 yyyy    t2
 zzzz    t1
 xxxx    t4
 xxxx    t2
```

1) Need to check, if the list contains duplicates, 
2) if duplicates are there, then check, if the duplicates has the value t4, 3) if t4 is there then ignore all.
so basically, what i need is a list with yyyy-->t2, zzzz-->t1 these values.

2nd scenario:

```html
xxxx    t1
yyyy    t2
zzzz    t1
xxxx    t2
```

1) Need to check, if the list contains duplicates, 
2) if duplicates are there, then check, if the duplicates has the value t4, 3) if no t4, then it should have all those values in list
so basically, what i need is a list with xxxx-->t1, yyyy-->t2, zzzz-->t1, xxxx-->t2 these values.

Comment: What did you try? in what form are your lists?? show some code, show you tried, show us what we have to work with

Comment: pasted the image of code snippet. incidents is the list object. Have to manipulate the list.

Comment: You clearly havent read the rules of the site - posting images of code is not a good idea, as if anyone thought this may have applied to them.. that image may go..  Im also not wandering off to other sites to look at blury images of code

Comment: var incidents = new List<SMIncident>();

Comment: in incidents object, i have duplicate records. while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            SMIncident smIncident = new SMIncident();
                            smIncident.GCSSReferenceNo = reader.GetString(0);
                            smIncident.assignmentGroup = reader.GetString(1); 
                            incidents.Add(smIncident);
                        }

Comment: Then try a little effort of your own to show what you tried to do to see if there are duplicates.. and also define what is a duplicate

Comment: i have tried in this way, But this is not working. var result = incidents.GroupBy(item => item.GCSSReferenceNo).SelectMany(g => g.Count() > 1 ? g.Where(x => x.assignmentGroup.Contains("Tier4")) : g.Skip(g.Count()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example based on your abstraction:

```
class AbstractList { public string field1; public string field2; }

List<AbstractList> lst = new List<AbstractList> {
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "xxxx", field2="t8"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "xxxx", field2="t1"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "xxxx", field2="t5"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "yyyy", field2="t1"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "yyyy", field2="t3"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "zzzz", field2="t1"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "zzzz", field2="t4"},
                    new AbstractList() { field1 = "xxxx", field2="t5"}
                  };



var res = from lstElement in lst
          where 
          (
              //following linq sub-expression get an exclusion sequence for your purpose
              from el_lstGrouped in 
              (
               from i in lst
               group i by new { i.field1 } into lstGrouped
               where lstGrouped.Count() > 1 
               select lstGrouped
              ).SelectMany(g => g)
              where el_lstGrouped.field2 == "t4"
              select new 
              {
                Field1 = el_lstGrouped.field1,
                Field2 = el_lstGrouped.field2
              }
           ).All(excluded => excluded.Field1 != lstElement.field1)
                 select lstElement;

foreach(var item in res)          
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.field1} - {item.field2}");
```

try snippet: http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=99262